# Computing error margin after unit conversions

Tags: mathematics, error-analysis

Suppose I've experimentally measured some length $L$ to be $10.50 \pm 0.05 cm$.

Using $2.54\;cm = 1\; in$, plugging this into a calculator, I get $L = 4.13385826772 \; in$. But $0.00000000002\;in$ is about $5.08E-11\; cm$ — far more precision than what I started with!

If I round this to $4.13 \;in$, I'm still working with precisions on the order of $0.0254\; cm$. If I round to $4.1\; in$, I've "lost" precision ($0.1\;in = 0.254\; cm$), which is absurd! Following this logic with converting the error $\pm 0.05\; cm$, I either gain or loose error, without including all digits of the conversion, however I cannot have gained precision.

What is the proper way to handle error and precision under such conversions (assuming, of course, that the conversions are "perfectly precise" (e.g., here $2.54 \; cm$ is precisely $1$ inch))?

Comment: To tackle such kinds of confusions, a standard set of rules are used in science. The concept is known as significant figures. Those rules are based to maintain the highest possible precision. You should look it up.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with significant figures.  10.50 has four significant figures and 0.05 has one.  The conversion of 2.54 cm to 1 inch has an infinite number of sig figs because it is an exact relation.  In other words 2.54000... cm = 1.00000... inch.  When you convert 10.50 cm to inches, you are essentially performing multiplication or division, and the sig figs in the answer is the same as the least significant figures number on the other side of the equation.  So, you have one factor with 4 sig figs and another with infinite sig figs, and your answer will have 4 sig figs.  Thus, 4.134 inches is your length.  Similarly, your uncertainty has 1 sig fig, so you will have ± 0.02 inches here.  When you combine the measurement with the uncertainty, the number of decimal places has to match. Here, the 0.02 forces the 4.134 to become 4.13.

10.50 ± 0.05 cm = 4.13 ± 0.02 in.

Answer (score 0):

$(10.50 \pm 0.05)\text{ cm}$ is $(4.13385826772\ldots \pm 0.01968503937\ldots)\text{ in}$. It isn't wrong to keep all of those digits. At the same time, it isn't *reasonable* to keep so many decimal places of an error margin whose value expresses your lack of confidence in the process that produced that value in the first place. If you really knew that many digits, then the error margin would be much smaller and most of the digits would be zero. In physics it's common practice to keep two digits of the error margin (after the leading zeros), and chop off the central value at the same decimal place. But it's technically not wrong to keep as many as you want.

I disagree with the comment and answer that suggested that this is about [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Significant_figures_rules_explained) (sig figs). The sig-fig rules are heuristic and only apply when you aren't given explicit error margins. If you were just given the value $10.50\text{ cm}$, the sig-fig rules say that you should assume an error of $\pm 0.01\text{ cm}$ (or perhaps $\pm 0.005\text{ cm}$ but I'll go with the former). Converting that to inches gets you $(4.133858\ldots \pm 0.003937\ldots)\text{ in}$. Now, if you want to report the result in the same way, i.e., without an explicit error margin, it is just plain wrong to report it as $4.133858\ldots$ because that implies a smaller error by the sig-fig rules. You must report it as $4.13$ or $4.134$. But when you have an explicit error margin, those rules don't apply and you can keep as many digits as you want.